# Store Character String in Clipboard (Copy/Paste)

Tags: r, copy, character, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

I have the following character string in R:

```
x <- "ABC"
```

Now, I want to use some R code to copy this character string into my cache (i.e. as I could do with the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + c`).

I assume there must be something like `copy_function(x)`, but I didn't find any appropriate R code.

As final result, the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + v` should print `"ABC"`.

How could I copy a character string with a function in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `writeClipboard(x)`.

From `help("writeClipboard")`

> Transfer text between a character vector and the Windows clipboard in MS Windows (only).

Then we can either press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or call

```
readClipboard()
# [1] "ABC"
```